# ReactNative: uploading image file to server using Axios is not working

Tags: react-native, axios

I am building a mobile application using ReactNative. My app needs to upload image file to the server. I am using Axios for that. But the file is always empty on the server-side.

This is my code.

```
const makeMultipartFormDataRequest = async ({
    path,
    data = null,
    headers = null
}) => {
    let accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    if (accessToken) {
        if (headers == null) {
            headers = {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        } else {
            headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        }
    }
    let formData = new FormData();
    if (data) {
        for (let prop in data) {
            let field = null;
            if (typeof data[prop] == "object" && data[prop]?.mime) {
                field = {
                    uri: data[prop].uri,
                    name: data[prop].name,
                    type: data[prop].mime
                }
            } else {
                field = data[prop];
            }
            // here image file is added proof_file field
            formData.append(prop, field);
        }
    }
    let url = config.apiEndpoint + path;

    return axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: headers
    });
}
```

As you see in the code, I put a comment where I put the file into the request. When I log the value in the console, I got this.

```
{"name": "IMG_0003.JPG", "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "/Users/waihein/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED2E89F7-F8C9-498E-9B80-41E13814A480/data/Containers/Data/Application/6AEBDAD9-A84C-4B33-95E5-0180F09B1AD5/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/E3B07A1B-B79D-43A0-A649-E05F8500783B.jpg"}
```

But the file is never sent in the request. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you are sending form data you should specify that as header like ‘headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },’. And I hope your backend api handles that.

Comment: Great. Just posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are sending form data you should specify that in the content type. Something like this,

`headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }`